# The same driver isn't being installed during every Ubuntu 12.04 install

Tags: installation, drivers, jockey

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 several times, and during installation sometimes the version 304 Nvidia driver gets installed sometimes the version 173. I checked the integrity of the DVD, of course. I'm just asking if it could cause some kind problem or not, should I be worried, or calm? hehehe

Comment: are you connected to the internet and somehow you get some updates for common drivers?

Comment: You mean during installing? Yes, and it's automatic.

Comment: So i guess from now on you will always end up having the 3xx driver :) pherhaps they did an update and for some short time the old driver was the actual stable one. I don't see any other reason here :)

Answer (score 0):

you should be calm. The 300 series drivers are the current stable version, the 173 is the older one. it will work with both, but ofc it's better the use the stable newer one... 
I would like to know which version is installed now.

Comment: Now 304.88 is installed.